# Are setcap-changes permanent

Tags: setcap

When using setcap for a file, is this change permanent or do I have to invoke setcap somewhere at boot time?

```
setcap cap_sys_nice fooexecutable
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [setcap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) on the file stores the [capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) in an extended attribute with a call to [setxattr](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setxattr). This extended attribute is stored like other attributes (ownership, rights...) in the filesystem.

> Since kernel 2.6.24, the kernel supports associating capability sets
>   with an executable file using setcap(8). The file capability sets are
>   stored in an extended attribute (see setxattr(2)) named
>   security.capability.

So, you don't have to reset your cap on each reboot.

Comment: what about if the file is replaced?

Comment: @ryanwinchester if only the content of the file is changed, no problem, but if the file is removed/recreated, the setcap capacity will be removed too.

Comment: :( ah, so that's my problem. i have a script that rebuilds a directory and then starts a server listening on port 80. i need to figure out a way to not have to run `setcap` every time

Comment: "if only the content of the file is changed, no problem" is not true. Changing the content of a file will cause its capabilities to be removed. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283408/2526

Answer (score 0):

The changes are permanent but I have experienced issues when used with `nodejs`.

You can use `authbind` to provide permission by user

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown user:user /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```